# HTML and CSS element problem display parameter

Tags: html, css

[][1]i  have a doubt about div element , as course taught that div element have by default display set to block but we can't align any other element side by side if it  has block display in order to do that we need inline-block or inline set to display, but i didn't set display to inline and move the block side by side using position parameter. how this thing works ????
how this happens please help me to understand this.

Comment: So you used position absolute to align it side by side ?

Comment: Please show us the code or what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: also you are technically wrong. You can align block level elements side by side on so many ways: `flexbox`, `css-grid`, `float` ...

Comment: **I downvoted** this post, why?? Because unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox:**

Wrap the block-level elements and apply `display: flex;` to the wrapping parent element.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  width: 25%;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
<div>Box 4</div>
```

**CSS-Grid:**

Wrap the block-level elements and apply `display: grid;` to the wrapping parent element. Use `grid-template-columns` to define how many columns should be in one row. In this example 4 columns with an equal width.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}


/* for styling purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
<div>Box 4</div>
```

**Float:**

apply `float` to the element itself to aling them next to each other. Note that this is a mis-used hack and should only be used within e-mail templates where you cant use flex or grid.

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
<div>Box 4</div>
```

Comment: My Question is not about how to align I said I align two block div side by side ,how it can be arranged side by side when there display property set to block

Comment: whats your actual question then? Whats the diffrence between arraneg elements side by side and align them side by side? And all my samples are block level elements (the have `display: block;` by default